# Pyspark randomly fails to write tos3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

Writing my word2vec model to S3 as following:

```
model.save(sc, "s3://output/folder")
```

I does it without problems usually, so no AWS credentials problem, but I randomly get the following error.

> 17/01/30 20:35:21 WARN ConfigurationUtils: Cannot create temp dir with
>   proper permission: /mnt2/s3 java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /mnt2
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
>           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.ConfigurationUtils.getTestedTempPaths(ConfigurationUtils.java:216)
>           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.initialize(S3NativeFileSystem.java:447)
>           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:111)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2717)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2751)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2733)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:377)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.(FileOutputCommitter.java:113)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.(FileOutputCommitter.java:88)
>           at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:41)
>           at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:339)

Have tried in various clusters and haven't managed to figure it out. Is this a known problem with pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to [SPARK-19247](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19247). As of today (Spark 2.1.0), ML writers repartition all data to a single partition and it can result in failures in case of large models. If this is indeed the source of the problem you can try to patch your distribution manually using [code from the corresponding PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16607/files).